# Tesseract.js example returns Uncaught TypeError: Tesseract.TesseractWorker is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, tesseract

I downloaded the tesseract.js library from https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js and the example code basic.html isn't working for me I get this error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Tesseract.TesseractWorker is not a constructor

I made a change of adding to fix a "file not found" error that appeared for some reason:

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="/dist/tesseract.dev.js"></script>
```

but I feel as if I'm missing a dependency

Here's the basic.html code:

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
<input type="file" onchange="const worker = new Tesseract.TesseractWorker({ corePath: '../../node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core.wasm.js' });worker.recognize(this.files[0]).progress(function(data){console.log(data)}).then(function(data){console.log(data)})">
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Tesseract.TesseractWorker is not a constructor

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. I you create  a method instead of putting all the code in onchange you can debug your code. Based on the error you are using the code the wrong way. Try new TesseractWorker().

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, it should be:

```
const { createWorker } = require("tesseract.js");
const worker = createWorker();
```

Do not use `new` as I've seen in several posts addressing this issue, at least for version 2.0.0-beta.2.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your working in the html portion when this error is thrown. But I am almost certain this error is coming from using the depreciated TesseractWorker when you attempt to create a constructor with,

```
const { TesseractWorker } = require("tesseract.js");
const worker = new TesseractWorker();
```

The TesseractWorker is depreciated in newer versions of tesseract.js and tesseract.js-core so you must use createWorker() instead.

```
const { createWorker } = require("tesseract.js");
const worker = new createWorker({
  logger: m => console.log(m),
});
```

This should remedy the error detailing that TesseractWorker is not a constructor, which depending on if you have versions 2.0+ of tesseract.js then you will be forced to use createWorker as TesseractWorker is depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
const createWorker = require("tesseract.js");
```

instead of,

```
const { TesseractWorker } = require("tesseract.js");        
const worker = new TesseractWorker();
```